# Awesome WM on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, debian, lxde

Has anyone succeeded in installing  [Awesome WM](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) on Raspbian? If yes, how do you switch between LXDE and Awesome?

I know that Arch will likely allow installation of Awesome WM as a window manager, but I find Debian and hence Raspbian easier to use, moreover I am fairly comfortable with Debian having used it on x86.

Comment: Lua runs really well on the Pi, so Awesome shouldn't be any issue. Just install it via your package manager.

Comment: @Jivings I did install it using apt-get but still have not figured out how to switch to it; startx still invokes LXDE and just typing awesome at the command line produces an error.

Comment: Ah right, got it. I'll post you an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to edit your `~/.xinitrc` file, removing or commenting this line:

```
exec ck-launch-session startlxde
```

and adding this line:

```
exec awesome
```

Then run `startx` as usual. The `.xinitrc` file defines the commands that execute when `X` is started.

Comment: What if `~/.xinitrc` does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

If `~/.xinitrc` does not exist, then you have to edit the file

```
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

comment the line

```
. /etc/X11/Xsession
```

and add the line

```
exec awesome
```

Then run `startx`.

Details found at the end of the debian manpage for startx https://manpages.debian.org/buster/xinit/startx.1.en.html.

Comment: This is essentially the same as the accepted answer, only instead of `~/.xinitrc` you are suggesting to edit `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`, which may lead to problems is this file is later updated by `apt`.